# How to use method delete with Json-server and Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, json-server

i'm doing a project and using `json-server` and `axios.js`, but i am with problem in the method `delete`.

My `axios.js`:

```js
remove = (id) => {
  axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:3000/people/', id)
    .then(function(response) {
      this.setState({
        filtered: response
      })
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

The route `http://127.0.0.1:3000/people` is of the `json.server`..

And the error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Someone would can help me ?

Answer (score 3):

you could request to the proper `uri` with `DELETE` method.

example:

```
DELETE /users/1

http://localhost:4000/users/1
```

Answer (score 2):

> try and change your json objects primary key name as id,I think you
> might have like this

```
   {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "task_id": 2,
      "task_name": "test2",
      "day": "may 20 2021",
      "reminder": true
    },
    {
      "task_id": 3,
      "task_name": "test3",
      "day": "june 2 2021",
      "reminder": true
    }
  ]
}
```

> change like this and try, It worked for me

```
  {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "task_name": "test2",
      "day": "may 20 2021",
      "reminder": true
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "task_name": "test3",
      "day": "june 2 2021",
      "reminder": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few different suggestions.

1) instead of using a comma, try `axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:3000/people/' + id)` so it will just think the url is `http://127.0.0.1:3000/people/3` or whatever

2) pass the id through a config object, so `axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:3000/people/', {params: {id: id})`

Once you get the deleting working: I believe the response of a DELETE request is an empty object, so you'd be setting `state.filtered = {}`. I assume you want the list of people without the person you just deleted?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, exacty i want a list without the person deleted

Comment: in that case, you will probably need to make another call to `axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/people/')` and the response will be the full list.

Comment: I already the method `get`, `post` too. I would want the method `delete` but be giving error :(

Comment: so first thing, you need to change the way you make the delete request to one of the options I provided above. Then it will not return that error. Then after that, you'll need to GET again.

Comment: could you please elaborate on last sentence? when using httpModule of angular, the DELETE method is removing whole data in db.json. GET after a DELETE return empty list.

Comment: Can we delete by querystring? http://localhost:3000/tasks/?id=2&task_name=test2

Answer (score 0):

I was just running into this issue. The axios.method(url/id) syntax seems to only work with GET and POST. For delete I used this:

```
axios({
  method: 'DELETE',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/people/' + id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/people/${id}`)